# use a pointer and be able to use class member functions

Tags: c++, pointers

So I have a pointer SparseMatrix *mat which holds values of the sparsematrix in a triplet format from a file. After I get the values, I would like to be able to just print it out using a print function I created in the SparseMatrix() class. However, I realize that this works if it wasn't a pointer and just 'mat'. I feel like this is something simple but I just cannot wrap my head around it. Any suggestions? Forgive me if this is an extremely noob question. Also, the reason I'm even using a pointer in the first place is because I am trying to visualize a sparsematrix using QT and my professor had given the basic backbone of the code. In that code, a private variable, SparseMatrix *mat was given.

Comment: Through a pointer you access class member functions using the `->`  or `*` operator to dereference the pointer. `obj->fun();`/`(*obj).fun();`

Comment: Does `mat->print()` work?

Comment: I have tried those already before. When I try to us mat->print(), the following error is given: window.cpp: In member function ‘void Window::drawMatrix(QPainter&, const SparseMatrix*)’:
window.cpp:115:14: error: passing ‘const SparseMatrix’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void SparseMatrix::print(const string&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]

Comment: You apparently have a `const` or `const&` reference to the `SparseMatrix` and `print()` is not declared as a `const` function as it probably should be.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ You are correct. I don't know how I did not catch that. I changed it to const and it works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Via pointers you can access your functions using `->`.